# Why are Dictionaries passed as a reference to classes while other types are copied?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why are Dictionaries passed as a reference to classes?

I used to think that when I pass variables to a class, they are copied.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        self.arg = arg

a = 'a'
m1 = MyClass(arg=a)
a = 'b'
print(m1.arg)  # Prints "a"
```

After using Python for a very long time I just figured out that when I pass a Dictionary, it is not copied, but referenced. So changing the variable afterwards, changes the classes variable. That was very unexpected.

```
d = {'a': 'a'}
m2 = MyClass(arg=d)
d['a'] = 'b'
print(m2.arg)  # Prints "{'a': 'b'} ... why suddenly 'b'?"
```

Does this happen only to dictionaries, or are there other types that are referenced? Why is it different anyway?

Comment: I think, this also applies to lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all boils down to mutability, since the object is mutable any changes to it won't return a new object but instead alter the existing reference. This change is then seen in all other names that hold a reference to that object.

Dictionaries and lists, two examples of mutable structures, apply here. `d['a'] = 'b'` mutates the dictionary so that change will be seen in `self.arg` which holds a reference to it.

Objects such as `int`s or `str`s, when operated on, return a new object so, even if you tried performing an operation like:

```
a += 'b'
```

which you'd expect mutates the `str` object and is reflected in `self.arg`, you'd be disappointed to find out it doesn't, since strings are immutable.

`a = 'b'` is completely different, it simply makes the name `a` refer to the string object `'b'`; it doesn't try to perform any operation on the existing value referred to by `a`; try the same statement with a dictionary.

Comment: So basically variables are always passed as references?

Comment: Exactly! The important part though is if that reference refers to an object that is mutable or an object that is immutable. That's where people usually trip up.